# Сортировка столбцов матрицы n*n - Java алгоритм

Tags: java

Всем привет, я написал вот такой вот алгоритм для сортировки столбцов в матрице n*n:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < tablica.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tablica.length; j++) {
                for (int k = i + 1; k < tablica.length; k++) {
                    if (tablica[i][j] > tablica[i][k]) {
                        b = tablica[i][j];
                        tablica[i][j] = tablica[i][k];
                        tablica[i][k] = b;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

И я уже пробовал писать этот алгоритм на листочке с матрицей 2*2, и он работает, почему компилятор
не может понять моих действий, сможет ли мне кто то помочь?
Вот фото:  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что у вас есть на выходе? ошибка, не корректные данные

Comment: Можете ли Вы рассказать по подробнее?

Comment: Это собственно к вам вопрос. Что вы имеете в итоге после выполнения данного кода?

Comment: @Dmitry добавил фото в вопросе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Какое у вас техническое задание? Что значит "сортировать стоблцы"?
2. Да и в целом: столбец это

[0][0]  >  [0][1]

[1][0]  >  [1][1]

[2][0]  >  [2][1]

[3][0]  >  [3][1]

т.е. меняется i-ый индекс, а не как у вас j-ый или k-ый.

Может в цикле:

```
for (int j = 0; j < tablica.length - 1; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < tablica.length; k++) {
       if (tablica[k][j] > tablica[k][j + 1]) {
           b = tablica[k][j];
           tablica[k][j] = tablica[k][j + 1];
           tablica[k][j + 1] = b;
        }
    }
}
```